# jupyterLab Wandb does not iterative

Tags: jupyter-lab, wandb

I try to use WanDB but when i use wandb.init() there is nothing.!

[image]

I am waiting a lot of time.

However, there is nothing in window.

This is working well in Kernel.

please.. help me guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Weights & Biases. If you're in a notebook the quickest thing you can do to get going with `wandb` is simply:

```
wandb.init(project=MY_PROJECT, entity=MY_ENTITY)
```

No `!wandb login`, `wandb.login()` or `%%wandb` needed. If you're not already logged in then `wandb.init` will ask you for you API key.

(curious where you found `%%wandb` by the way?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

%env WANDB_API_KEY=<PUT_KEY_HERE>

This worked on jupyter for me, and so you don't need to put your key everytime you run.